# Check entry against several columns

Tags: excel

I've got a list of countries in Column A; I want to structure a formula in Column B, that will check if that country appears in lists that are unrelated to one another in Columns, C, D, E, and F. So if Argentina appears in Column C, D, E, and F, then the output in B1 would be TRUE.

I've tried: `COUNTIFS(C2:C42, "Argentina", D2:D42, "Argentina", E2:E49, "Argentina", F2:F36, "Argentina")` However I get a `#VALUE` error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Argentina` is in A1, please try in B1:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(C:C,A1)>0,COUNTIF(D:D,A1)>0,COUNTIF(E:E,A1)>0,COUNTIF(F:F,A1)>0)
```

Comment: You can even go one more step, removing the `>0` from the formula.

Comment: I know what you mean :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, [`COUNTIFS()` assumes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) that the values are on the same row. Thus, you should use it only in this scenaro.

---

Your formula is quite ok and should be working, **but** you should make sure that the ranges are with the same length. Currently the last 2 ranges finish on row `36` and `49` and the first two on row `42`, thus you get the Excel error.

Here is how to do it:

```
=COUNTIFS(C2:C42,"Argentina", D2:D42,"Argentina",E2:E42,"Argentina", F2:F42, "Argentina")
```

Or in general, refer to the whole columns like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"Argentina", D:D,"Argentina",E:E,"Argentina", F:F, "Argentina")
```

If you want a boolean value as an answer, you can simply write:

`=IF(COUNTIFS(YOUR-FORMULA-HERE),TRUE,FALSE)`

Comment: @pnuts - true. I simply saw the error of the OP formula and rewrote it without one.